# Excel VBA Currency Erronous Display

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a MAC, version: 10.11.16 "el Capitan"

I hope this all makes sense.

I'm learning VBA, using a book named "Learn VBA Fast, Vol 1, Excel Function Design Course"

The message boxes in the code display the correct values, but the value is the 
spreadsheet cell is absurd (See Below)

Why is this happening?

I've set up the spreadsheet as follows:

Old Price as currency

New Price as currency

Discount as percentage

I've also tried the discount cells

- as custom:  `0.00`
- as number: `-1234.00` (2 decimal places)
- as currency:  `-$1234.00` (2 decimal places)

The result is always the same values--no matter what configuration I set the discount cell to be.

The spreadsheet is setup like this

```
old Price  |            New Price        |       Discount
----------------------------------------------------------

$12.50     |     $18,483,160,287,229.10   |     10%

----------------------------------------------------------

$13.25     |      $18,483,160,287,229.10   |     10%

----------------------------------------------------------
```

The function calls, in the "New Price" cells is as follows:

`=NewPrice(E43,G43)` and `=NewPrice(E44,G43)`

The function code follows:

```
Option Explicit

Function NewPrice(OldPrice As Currency, Discount As Currency) As Currency

        Discount = OldPrice * Discount

        NewPrice = OldPrice - Discount

        MsgBox "Old price = " & OldPrice & vbCrLf & _
 "Discount = " & Discount & vbCrLf & "New price = " & NewPrice     

End Function
```

Question:  Why is the display value so crazy wrong?

Comment: I can't get that output.  I get the correct output.  The issue must be with the data some how.

Comment: Works fine for me too (on Win7)

Comment: Works ok on Win7 (Old Price as currency with 2 decimal places, Discount as Percentage with 0 decimal places)

Comment: I can't get that either - have you tried starting with a blank workbook and just running this example only?